# how to create a load balancer for app engine and cloud run

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I currently have two services that do the same thing but in a different way, one is in the app engine and the other in cloud run and I need to create a load balancer in which the load can be shared by a single endpoint.

example

100 requests arrive and the balancer instructs it to make 50 requests to the app engine and the remaining 50 to cloud run.

example.com/appengine/all
example.com/cloudrun/todos

Answer (score 4):

You can use one [serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) per service (1 for cloud run, 1 for App Engine) and use [URL Map](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map) to route the query to the corresponding NEG